# What is the difference between edits and revisions?

Tags: support, badges, revisions-list, edits

I notice that for the badge *Strunk and White* I need to have *Edited 80 posts*.

I can also see in my *Activity* that I've made 329 revisions.

I don't currently have the *Strunk and White badge* which got me wondering, What is the difference between the number of revisions I've made, and the number of posts I've edited?

Is it that my 329 revisions weren't accross 80 posts? (I haven't checked this to be sure but I will)

Comment: On MSO: [Posts edited count on profile is way less than my revsions count?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300855/4642212).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edits and revisions are the same thing. The word "revisions" tends to be used more when referring to edits in the revision history.

You may not have the badge because:

1. Edits that only change the tags do not count.
2. Multiple edits to the same post only count as one.
3. Edits on your own posts do not count.

329 sounds curious, but I'd bet you're right up near the 80 mark at that number. You should be able to visit the `/review` page to see how many eligible edits you've made.

Comment: Thanks @animuson. I didn't know there was somewhere I could see the actual number. Perfect thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You get the *Strunk and White* badge if you edit 80 different posts, which are not your own. If the edit is for a question, it should change the body, or the title, not just the tags.