# “Total number of edits” tooltip should be reworded

Tags: bug, tooltips, wording

The tooltip appearing on the “*n* posts edited” text on the impact card on the profile page currently reads

> Total **number of edits** made to improve existing posts

However the text itself says “**posts** edited”:

[image]

When clicking on that link the “number of edits” is actually different:

[image: 399 Revisions, or edits, not posts edited]

I’d suggest to reword it like this:

> Total number of existing posts improved by edits

---

### Edit: not a duplicate of [What is the difference between edits and revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138231)

Note, this is a rewording request. I’m not asking why the numbers are different, because I know that the one thing are the number of *posts* edited, the other thing the number of *edits* made to posts.

The problem I’m trying to point out is that the tooltip that is supposed to describe the number of *posts* edited accidentally describes the number of *edits*.

Ultimately, I’m asking for the tooltip to be changed in such a way that it describes what it’s supposed to describe, as it’s a bit confusing and is most likely a mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between edits and revisions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138231/what-is-the-difference-between-edits-and-revisions)

Comment: @RobertLongson It’s not a duplicate of that question. That question is asking about the differences and nuances between “edits” and “revisions” or what the difference between “posts edited” and “edits made” is. My “question” is pointing out a wording error, because the tooltip _does describe something different_ than the text it belongs to. None of the other tooltips do this. Moreover, it’s about this specific tooltip (so far) and I’ve googled the phrase within the tooltip — with no results. The proposed duplicate target doesn’t even mention any wording error or any tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

Today I was the "victim" of this discrepancy when I investigated a Meta GIS SE question about why rep gains of 2 had stopped when a user had only made 295 edits - for more details see [Not getting +2 reputation from edits](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4979/115)

In order to see how 500 suggested edits could have been hit I needed to look at the suggestions tab of their profile:

`https://<site>.stackexchange.com/users/<userid>/<username>?tab=activity&sort=suggestions`