# What is the difference between revised and suggested edits?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

While my question bears similarity in title to [What is the difference between edits and revisions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138231/374170)
 which appears to be a duplicate of [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/374170), I am not asking about badges or obtaining them.  I would like clarification on what constitutes a post being assigned the **suggested** flag vs the **revised** flag on posts you have edited, **without having the required reputation to make revisions**.

What I am wanting to know is, are these flags assigned automatically based on the amount of changes in an edit, or did one of the reviewers make a change to your edit before approving it?

Here is a screenshot of what I am wanting clarification on:
[image]

You can view this screen by clicking on your reputation at the top of the screen then clicking on the *all actions* tab under your activity summary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "suggested" item in the actions list refers to the suggested edit itself. This is kind of a "draft", which can be either approved or rejected. The "suggested" item appears as soon as you submit the suggested edit. Until reviewed, it will show "pending edit" in the next column.

When this suggested edit is reviewed, one of two things can happen:

- If the edit was rejected, the "pending edit" will become "rejected edit" and no further items will be added to your actions list.
- If the edit was approved, the "pending edit" will become "approved edit", and a new action item will be added, with the time of approval, saying "revised".

The "revised" action item is exactly the same item that will show for users with full edit privilege. Once approved, the suggested edit becomes a full edit by all means. Think of this as a draft that was published.

Answer (score 3):

A suggested edit is someone suggesting an edit that doesn't have the privilege of editing the post without approval.  A revision is someone editing the post without requiring approval of anyone else to make the edit.

Comment: @Bill it doesn't change my answer.

Answer (score 1):

While I was trying to modify my question to provide even more clarity, everything suddenly became clear.  I will provide an example of why I was confused and demonstrate what I was doing wrong.  Perhaps someone else will benefit.

At the time I originally posted my question I had only 95 reputation on sister site serverfault.com.  I kept noticing in my activity history that posts I edit were later being revised.  Here is an example:
[image]
[image]

I had not realized that the the "revised" was, as Shadow Wizard eloquently explained, my draft being published at the time it had been approved - which in some cases can take a while depending on the complexity of the edit.

So my confusion was that these "revised" were popping up in my history long after I had forgotten I had "suggested an edit".

Keep in mind that I am newly active on the stack sites, so while this might be obvious to those of you with 900k reputation, it wasn't so obvious to me.